# Obter imagem da pasta "Resources" do android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, resources

Bom dia,

Tenho uma aplicação android feita em C# via xamarin.
Nessa aplicação, tem um relatório feito em HTML que é exibido em um WebView. Esse relatório precisa exibir uma imagem (PNG) que está armazenada na pasta Resources do meu projeto. Para fazer isso, a minha ideia é obter a imagem da pasta Resources e copia-la para o diretório que está meu arquivo HTML e no fonte do HTML eu acessaria essa imagem. Porém não consegui acessar a pasta Resources.

Conclusão: **como copio um arquivo da pasta Resources para outro diretório?**

Desde já, obrigada.

Comment: Inclua o seu código, mostre como está tentando fazer e indique o erro que encontra

Comment: @LeandroAngelo já encontrei a resolução e coloquei como resposta aqui. De toda forma, obrigada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.imagem_origem);
string path = diretorioDestino + "imagem_destino.png";
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
{
     bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
}
```